# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use nea

Tags: php, mariadb

**I get this error**
//ERROR

> ERRORINSERT INTO new_comp_reg (phno , fullname , address , dept , desc) VALUES ('','','','','')
>       You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc) VALUES ('','','' ,'','')' at line 1

**PHP**

```
<?php

    $servername = 'mysql.hostinger.in';
    $username = '';
    $password = '';
    $dbname = 'u424351292_icrcm';

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $phone_no = $_POST['phno'];
        $full_name = $_POST['fullname'];
        $location = $_POST['address'];
        $department = $_POST['dept'];
        $description = $_POST['desc'];
    }

        $conn = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);

        if($conn->connect_error)
        {
            die("Connection Failed" . $conn->connect_error);
        }

        $sql = "INSERT INTO new_comp_reg (phno , fullname , address , dept , desc)  VALUES ('$phone_no' , '$full_name' , '$location' , '$department' , '$description')";

        if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)
        {
            echo "Complaint Registered";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "ERROR".$sql."<br>".$conn->error;
        }

    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

//ERROR

> ERRORINSERT INTO new_comp_reg (phno , fullname , address , dept , desc) VALUES ('','','','','')
>       You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc) VALUES ('','','' ,'','')' at line 1

Comment: Desc is a reserved keyword, you should escape it

Answer (score 2):

`desc` is a [reserved keyword in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) and needs to be escaped by backticks.

```
INSERT INTO new_comp_reg (..., `desc`)  VALUES (...)
```

or change your column name to `description` for instance.

BTW you are not escaping your user input which could lead to syntax errors and SQL injections. Use Prepared Statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $phone_no = $_POST['phno'];
    $full_name = $_POST['fullname'];
    $location = $_POST['address'];
    $department = $_POST['dept'];
    $description = $_POST['desc'];
}

    $conn = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);

    if($conn->connect_error)
    {
        die("Connection Failed" . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO new_comp_reg VALUES ('$phone_no' , '$full_name' , '$location' , '$department' , '$description')";

    if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)
    {
        echo "Complaint Registered";`enter code here`
    }
    else
    {
        echo "ERROR".$sql."<br>".$conn->error;
    }

$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

I would say that it is

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO new_comp_reg (phno , fullname , address , dept , desc)  VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($phone_no)."' , '".mysql_real_escape_string($full_name)"' , '".mysql_real_escape_string($location)"' , '".mysql_real_escape_string($department)"' , '".mysql_real_escape_string($description)"')";
```

This would actually improve your protection. Also check your column name as sad above it might be that you referenced one wrong.

Comment: This answer doesn't solve the problem and on top of that suggest a use of deprecated API. **Do not USE THIS!**