# How to use a reserved word in SQL as a table name?

Tags: sql, mariadb

When using this query :

```
INSERT INTO order (order_quantity)
           VALUES ('50')
```

I'm getting an error :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'order (order_quantity) VALUES('50')' at line 146

What's wrong with my query?

Comment: Please edit your question with a better title and tags, this does not appear to be anything to do with php but rather sql - and which sql is that exactly, please tag it with that.  Please add additional clarification of the exact single question in the body of the question.  As it stands now, the first sentence appears to be the answer, clarify why that is not so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use nea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34321222/you-have-an-error-in-your-sql-syntax-check-the-manual-that-corresponds-to-your)

Comment: I edited the title, please update if this is not the actual question.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to edit the title for the OP. Especially when it's not even clear, what the actual question is.

Comment: @Olafant Perhaps, but as OP is a new user it is better in my opinion to illustrate to the OP how to improve the question rather than simply closing it as unclear what you are asking when the actual question can be inferred from the original post.

Comment: @Olafant the title is far more clearer than the previous *"Facing some issue"* one.

Comment: I edited the question to be more (I hope) StackOverflow compliant.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss if i could upvote again your comment on guidance to an OP, i would.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg Strictly speaking PrakashG is correct and closing as a duplicate is a valid response if this were not a new contributors question.  I did however also not favor that question due to the title of it, and the answers were IMHO less clear that the one I up-voted here.  I tend to work with "Be kind always, you never know what struggles any person is dealing with and we all have those" - but honestly at times I may be more direct in my response at times, usually after repeated attempts to communicate have failed.

Answer (score 18):

Reserved words are not recommended for use as database, table, column, variable or other object names. If you desire to use a reserved word is used as an object name in ANSI standard syntax, it must be enclosed in double-quotes to allow the Relational Engine (whichever that one is) that the word is being used as an object and not as a keyword in the given context.

Here are some examples specific to different SQL engines:

`order` is a SQL Keyword, used to sort results (`ORDER BY ...`)

Wrap backticks around it if you are using [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sorting-rows.html) or [Maria DB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/order-by/)

```
INSERT INTO `order` (order_quantity) VALUES ('50');
```

Wrap brackets around it if you are using [MS SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
INSERT INTO [order] (order_quantity) VALUES ('50');
```

Wrap double quotes around it if you are using [pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/queries-order.html)

```
INSERT INTO "order" (order_quantity) VALUES ('50');
```

---

In example, nothing (but common sense) prevents you from creating a database named `INSERT` with a table `INTO` having a column `VALUE(42)`

[image]

Yes, this query works :

```
USE [INSERT];
SELECT [INTO].[VALUE(42)] FROM [INTO];
```

Comment: Even a _reserved_ keyword.

Comment: @jarlh What's the difference?

Comment: And the double quotes delimiting is the ANSI/ISO SQL standard way!

Comment: @jarlh feel free to edit if you want to add more details

Comment: Keywords are these words used when defining the SQL syntax. Some are reserved (e.g. `ORDER`), some are not (e.g. `DESC`) - according to ANSI SQL. However, products may have other sets of reserved words.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss very nice, thanks. Thank you Jarlh for the precisions

Comment: Well, I might have done a better job of the wording, please feel free to correct my quickly pasted grammar (it is pretty atrocious as I did it)